# Regression for continuous response and ordinal predictors ranked relative to each other

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, ranks

I would like to predict the value of a continuous response variable $y$ from some predictor variables $x_1, ..., x_n$ which are all ordinal insofar as their numerical values in my observations are limited in meaning to rank against each other; being numerically greater or less than another observation in some $x$ indicates that this observation indicates that this observation is superior or or inferior to the other in that $x$ but the degree of difference is not meaningful. Nor is the relative importance of each predictor $x$'s contribution to $y$ known. What is this sort of model called?

Comment: Unless you want to impose some sort of monotonicity to the effects of the ordinal variable's levels, you can treat it as a categorical predictor.

Comment: Right, I could do that, but then I would throw away the useful information of the monotonicity if I collapsed all levels to one qualitative variable. I do want to constrain the interpretation of the levels by the model as they are not independent.

Comment: You should leave the levels to be unconstrained and test monotonicity, rather than imposing it. I will see if I can write an answer that elucidates this point.